# Holomorphic functions and connected sets.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a connected set. Prove that $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ if and only if there is a function $F$ holomorphic in U such that $F^\prime=f$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: For example, why do you think this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = \mathbb{C} - \{0\}.$  Put $f(z) = 1/z$, $z\in U$. This function is holomorphic.  Suppose there is some $F$ so $F' = f$. Then
$$\int_{S^1} f(z)\,dz = \int_0^{2\pi} F'(z)\,dz
= \int_0^{2\pi} F'(e^{it})ie^{it}\,dt =  \int_0^{2\pi} (F(e^{it}))'dt = 0.$$
But $$\int_0^{2\pi} {dz\over z} = 2\pi.$$
No such $F$ can exist.   Your domain must be simply connected.